# Mixed Service Codes/Descriptions database

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am facing an issue regarding a significantly large database that I have to reorganize. There are two columns, one consists of the Service Code of an item and next is a column containing the Description of the relevant item. Below is an example:

```
TSB Trim Booklet
LMN Loading Manual
GLM Grain Loading Manual
```

etc.

There are a total of 170 different items.

The problem is this: On a different Excel file, there is a column containing (mixed around 16,000 times) only the Descriptions of the items without the 3-letter Service Code.

How can I link them quickly?

Comment: Have you tried a `vlookup`?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: you want to take the service code from file 1 and apply it to the descriptions from file 2 and a single description always has the same service code.

Use the following formula in file 2 (the big one you want to add service codes to)

```
=INDEX([file1]Sheetname!$A:$A,MATCH([file2]Sheetname!A2,[file1]Sheetname!$B:$B,0))
```

Where

```
[file1]Sheetname!$A:$A
```

is the column with service codes in the file/sheet with both the code and the description

```
[file2]Sheetname!A2
```

is the cell with description in the file/sheet with just descriptions

and

```
[file1]Sheetname!$B:$B
```

is the column with descriptions in the file/sheet with both the code and the description